Фунция а не возвращает измененный объект а при console.log() внутри функции уже выводит
let a = document.querySelector('#class_btn').onclick = () => {
    let topic = document.getElementById('topic').value;
    let stud_check1 = document.getElementById('stud_id1').checked;
    let stud_check2 = document.getElementById('stud_id2').checked;
    let stud_check3 = document.getElementById('stud_id3').checked;
    let gr3 = {
        stud1:0,
        stud2:0,
        stud3:0
    };

    if(stud_check1){
        gr3.stud1 = 1
    }
    if(stud_check2){
        gr3.stud2 = 1
    }
    if(stud_check3){
        gr3.stud3 = 1
    }
   console.log(gr3) // хотя тут выводит так как пользователь выбирает на странице
    //  return gr3;
}
console.log(a)// при выводе таким образом выводит значения {stud1: 0, stud2: 0, stud3: 0}
}


начни отсюда - [ask]

Вообще, при console.log(a) вы должны были получить в консоль тело функции, а вот если вернуть в функции return и сделать console.log(a()) то значение показывает правильное.
